# Two urls, one wordpress site, how to do that

Tags: wordpress, url, ftp, dns, hosting

I have two url's for two different countries, however, the website is and should be the same.

Both url's are on the same hosting.

It looks like this:

> HOSTING A - Domain A > Public_html > files
>
> HOSTING A - Domain B > Public_html > subfolder > wordpress installation

Is it possible to link the domain A to the domain B wordpress?

It's not possible to just change the site url in wordpress, because I already did that with the subfolder the wordpress installation is in.

Comment: Option 1: http://www.hashbangcode.com/blog/using-jquery-load-content-page-without-iframe
Option 2: http://www.willmaster.com/library/web-development/URL-masking.php

Would that work for you, @PixelProof

Comment: @DJSquared I did the URL Masking for now, hope to find a better solution in the future though. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option 1: http://www.hashbangcode.com/blog/using-jquery-load-content-page-without-iframe
Option 2: http://www.willmaster.com/library/web-development/URL-masking.php

Either of these would work for your purpose.